# In Symfony is it possible to if a route matched, forward to other route

Tags: symfony

I have two routes in two separated bundles: bundleA_route, bundleB_route. In my /app/config/routing.yml I load them as resources like:

```
bundle_a_routing:
    resource: "@SomeABundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

bundle_b_routing:
    resource: "@SomeBBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

In most cases this sequence is required, first of all try to match on routes in `bundle_a_routing`, and *then* try to match on routes in `bundle_b_routing`, but in only one case I want to make an exception, I want a single route defined in `bundle_b_routing` to be matched before the more "concessive" route defined in `bundle_a_routing`:

```
route_in_bundle_a:
    path: /admin/{path}
    defaults: { _controller: SomeABundle:SomeCtrl:someAction }
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
        path: ^(.*)$

route_in_bundle_b:
    path: /admin/download/{formId}/{fileName}
    defaults: { _controller: SomeBBundle:SomeOtherCtrl:someOtherAction }
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
        formId: \d+
        fileName: ^([a-fA-F0-9]{32}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,222})?)$
```

Now the request URI "http://servername/web/app_dev.php/admin/download/12/23d2fff7f606e93acac9ede5b4e2b394.png" matches the first, but I want to match the second...what is the official scenario in cases like this?

Comment: Are you sure that your `route_in_bundle_b` is called anytime at all? It looks to me like `route_in_bundle_a` supersedes it in any way. Can you provide a URL where the request would pass `route_in_bundle_a` and get to `route_in_bundle_b`?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order in which you are importing routes, so the route http://servername/web/app_dev.php/admin/download/12/23d2fff7f606e93acac9ede5b4e2b394.png will trigger the route_in_bundle_b first and the routes that doesn't have the download segment will not trigger it and will trigger the route_in_bundle_a rule.